# Consul periodically fails on "No Cluster Leader"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul, reportportal

I have a docker-compose with consul used for services communication ([ReportPortal](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal)).

It's deployed on ubuntu, consul container has a mounted volume for data. It worked some time (few months) with no problem, but recently started failing periodically (once a 2-3 days) with "No cluster leader" error.

I've found a one-time solution:

- to stop all services (docker-compose stop);
- to delete all in consul `data` folder;
- to start all;

But I cannot find out the root cause.

PS: You can see the docker-compose yaml:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reportportal/reportportal/master/docker-compose.yml -o docker-compose.yml
```

PS2: I don't see any lack of resources on host.

I would very appreciate if you could help me :)

Comment: it's complicated question to answer. We never faced this issue before. My guesses it restarts due to any reason, and can't bootstrap with previous config saved in `data/consul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReportPortal v5 is about to go STABLE.
There will be no Consul in it.

Comment: Waiting for release version :)